# UIPickerView Done button not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UITextField on which I have put UIPickerView. When user click on textfield, pickerview will show up just like a keyboard. I am trying to remove the pickerview with the help of Done button in it's toolbar but it's not doing so. Below is my code.

I have tried looking for ideas online, but didn't solve my purpose. Can anyone help me out with this, like what I am missing here.

```
-(void)pickerViewSetUp
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    NSLog(@"%f %f",screenWidth,screenHeight);

    _myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc]init];
    _myPickerView.delegate = self;
    _myPickerView.dataSource = self;

    UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, 44)];
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(hidePicker)];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexible = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    [toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexible,doneButton, nil]];
    [_myPickerView addSubview:toolBar];
}

-(void)hidePicker
{
    [_toss resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
{
    if (textField == _toss)
    {
        _toss.inputView = _myPickerView;
    }
}
```

### Solution

As a temp solution I have used a tap gesture, so when a user selects from picker view and taps on screen, pickerview is gone. Below is my code: 
Inside viewDidLoad

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hidePicker)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

and then

```
-(void)hidePicker
{
    [_toss resignFirstResponder];
}
```

I would still love to solve the mystery behind done button not hiding my pickerview.

Comment: Does your `_toss` have the right reference??

Comment: Yes, in my .h file
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *toss;

Comment: create a brak point in hidePicker method and check the value of toss when you press done button...

Comment: Where is your code to show / remove the picker?

Comment: @Goodsquirrel I am calling (void)pickerViewSetUp method inside viewDidLoad method. And when "_toss" textfield is selected, pickerview shows up just like keyboard from bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Try calling

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

in `-(void)hidePicker`

Answer (score 0):

Not getting what you actually want to do.
Just to remove that picker you 
Can You try :

> `[_myPickerView removeFromSuperview];`

in `-(void)hidePicker`